# No Persistence provider for EntityManager named eclipselink

Tags: java, jpa

I am trying to set up JPA on my web application but I am getting the error:

No Persistence provider for EntityManager named StorePU

My persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
      <persistence-unit name="StorePU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/NotesDB</non-jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties/>
      </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Connection:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class DBUtil 
{
    private static final EntityManagerFactory emf =
            Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("StorePU");

    public static EntityManagerFactory getEmFactory() {
        return emf;
    }

    public static void close()
    {
        emf.close();
    }
}
```

I have added the necessary library EclipseLink (JPA 2.1).

I tried adding

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</p‌​rovider>
```

to my persistence file but I still get that error.

Stack trace:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at Store.data.CustomerRepository.insert(CustomerRepository.java:25)
    at store.service.CustomerService.insert(CustomerService.java:38)
    at Store.util.TestingInsert.main(TestingInsert.java:20)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named StorePU
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
    at Store.data.DBUtil.<clinit>(DBUtil.java:9)
    ... 3 more
C:\Users\buttons\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

[Eclipselink in class path image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1a6J.png)

I am using MySQL as my database and MySQL connector as my JDBC driver

Comment: Please add the error stack trace. Do you have eclipselink in your classpath? What is your database configuration & jdbc driver?

Comment: Added more information.

Comment: where is the information about jdbc driver, db name, server, etc? i mean how fo you tell that stuff to EL?